# In excel how do I change the spreadsheet name from lower case to upper case

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA in Excel **is there a way to change the tab name for the worksheet from lower case to upper case?**

I have a workbook with over 50 sheets and changing the names individually does not appear to be a very appealing option.

The **name of the spreadsheet is in cell A1 and in uppercase already**. Just need the actual sheet name to be uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
for each ws in Workbooks("").worksheets
    ws.name = ucase(ws.name)
    'or
    ws.name = ucase(ws.range("A1"))
next
```

Comment: Tried this in a macro as below, however, getting error message  run-time error '438' object doesn't support this property or method on the line For each.     'Sub Lower2UpperCase()

Dim wbBook As Workbook

Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook


For Each ws In wbBook("").Worksheets
    'ws.Name = UCase(ws.Name)
    'or
    ws.Name = UCase(ws.Range("A1"))
Next

End Sub'

Comment: Sorted just needed to change wbBook("").Worksheets to wbBook.Worksheets. Works fine now. thanks appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
Sub Lower2UpperCase()

Dim wB As Workbook, _
    wS As Worksheet
Set wB = ActiveWorkbook

For Each wS In wB.Worksheets
    'Only thing needed if ALL of your sheets'name are in A1 in Upper case :
    wS.Name = wS.Range("A1")

    'If all the sheets'name are in A1 but not all in Upper case :
    'wS.Name = UCase(wS.Range("A1"))

    'Take the name of the sheet and change the case to all Upper case :
    'wS.Name = UCase(wS.Name)
Next wS

End Sub
```